# How can I add an integer across one column in a 2d array of two columns where column one is strings and column two is integers... using numpy?

Tags: python, addition

I am just starting out learning python...

I'm practicing on my own some things I've learned from DataCamp...

what I'm trying to do is add two years, to the ages of two people in a 2d array...

e.g.

people=np.array([["you',20],["me",21]])

I remember that with NumPy arrays all elements should be the same in order to do maybe do a calculation like this. But can't I just create a second np.array and then do the calculation across the second column e.g. people[:,1] since just that column is integers and I would be applying the calculation to only that column? Or is it just not possible because the array people has ints and strs?

noob question but I'm just trying to learn here

Answer (score 2):

NumPy arrays work best if all elements have the same datatype. Let's have a look at your initialiser:

```
>>> people = np.array([['you', 20], ['me', 21]])
array([['you', '20'],
       ['me', '21']], dtype='<U3')
```

NumPy saw those strings and deduced the data type `<U3`, i.e. little-endian unicode strings of length 3. If you want to perform arithmetic on the second column, this is not what you want. You could set a more general data type in the constructor:

```
>>> people = np.array([['you', 20], ['me', 21]], dtype='object')
array([['you', 20],
       ['me', 21]], dtype=object)
```

In general, having an `object` data type is not great as it is inefficient (and I imagine that some functions will not properly operate on these arrays). However, your desired arithmetic works now. Let's age everybody by 30 years:

```
>>> people[:, 1] += 30
array([['you', 50],
       ['me', 51]], dtype=object)
```

In conclusion: if you can avoid it, don't use strings with numbers in the same NumPy array. Perhaps keeping two separate arrays would be suitable for your purposes. In the longer term, I would recommend you try out [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which is designed to handle much more general and mixed datasets.

Comment: Now I see where I made the mistake... I was picturing an excel sheet mentally, then forgetting the purpose of the arrays and calculations. Which is to deal with the calculations and not the names of the people. After calculating the data with numpy (which would be all integers) I could then paste my results back in to the excel sheet and the names would be there just fine. Duh! Lol